# Autogenerate java classes for facebook Graph Api service

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to have all the POJOs autogenerated that are needed when consuming the Faceboook Graph API Service via Jersey? Or is the only way to manually create all objects by looking at the graph API explorer output?

(The facebook.xsd does not work. It contains more classes than the API returns while not containing all of them (e.g. "post"). I don't think it is intended for the purpose of consuming the RESTful Graph service)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because RESTful APIs are not supposed to have a rigid, predefined structure.

But most java wrappers provide the most used classes like `Post` or `User`. Check [restfb](http://restfb.com/) or [spring-social-facebook](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/).